# How to change background of UITableViewController in GroupedStyle

Tags: c#, colors, xamarin.ios, uitableview

I'm trying to change the color of a `UITableViewController` when using a split view. Then the style is set to grouped, the background seems to light gray no matter what.

I create a new iPad Split Application solution and add the following code to `RootViewController`:

```
public RootViewController () : base( UITableViewStyle.Grouped) // base ("RootViewController", null)
        {

            this.TableView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
            this.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
            this.View.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Green.CGColor;
            this.TableView.BackgroundView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Brown;
```

I'm pulling my hair out trying to work out why its always light gray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not change the color of the controller but of one (or many) of its views.

Also it's generally `TintColor` that must be used (not `BackgroundColor`). A bit confusing (I think it's related to the use of gradients, over the background, used in many place - but I could be wrong).